# How to automatically stretch raster in QGIS? (ArcGIS DRA dynamic range adjustment analogue)

Tags: qgis, raster, stretch

I am looking for ArcGIS's dynamic range adjustment (DRA) analouge in QGIS for raster data sets. And I have found such button:

[image]

But I have to click it every time I move raster's extent.

**There is any way to automate manual clicking the button?**

Comment: You can right-click on the Layer -> Stretch to current Extent. But that is not automatic.

Comment: Will be available in 3.0. See [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/1583)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn on ArcGIS's dynamic range adjustment (DRA) analouge in QGIS 3.12 go to:

Raster `Layer Properties` => `Symbology` => `Min / Max Value Settings`

and set `Statistic extent` to `Updated canvas`.

How it works [video (size - 20 MB)](https://i.ibb.co/gtvC144/ojh-HMg-A0-Y3.gif).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this feature is not available without some python scripting, but will be available in 3.0.

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/1583

> @QGIS-feature-tracker QGIS-feature-tracker added this to the QGIS 3.0 milestone on Dec 16, 2016

Answer (score 5):

Nice find by [@RoVo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87998/rovo)! There is also an alternative.

---

### For QGIS 2.x

We could use a little bit of Python where each time the extent of the canvas changes, we connect the signal that is emitted to a function which triggers the button you mentioned.

So you could use something like the following in the **Python Console**:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction

def stretch_raster():
    try:
        layer = iface.activeLayer()
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
            iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionLocalCumulativeCutStretch' ).trigger()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.connect(stretch_raster)
```

---

Note that the button will only be triggered if a raster layer is selected from the Layers Panel. When you want to disconnect the signal from the function, you can use:

```
iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.disconnect(stretch_raster)
```

Comment: Nice one. Maybe the better answer ...  ;-)

Comment: @RoVo - Thanks but eventually this answer will be obsolete, particularly when QGIS 3.0 comes out relatively soon :)